# MVC HTML RadioButtonFor Control Calender as options

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In ASP.Net MVC Razor, I need to provide a radio button control with two options. One option is Static, the second option is a Calendar control that picks up the date. How to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

**1.Use jquery date picker for pick date from calander.**

links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

html:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

**2.**`@html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.DateParameter)` **for inserting manually.**

Format should be like `1990-06-20 08:03`

Other wise you can take string format of date & time and later covert it to `DateTime`  format in controller by using `DateTime.Parse()`